# How to use custom PolicySpi

Tags: java, security, permissions, policy

I'm trying to implement a custom `java.security.Permission` type, which should be checked at runtime (so no policy file, but in code). This checking is done by a `java.security.Policy`. I understood I should implement my own `java.security.PolicySpi` for this.

I cannot find any explanation on how to initialise and use a PolicySpi, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Checking permissions

In your question you stated that you then want to check the permission with `java.security.Policy`, but without using a `spi.policy` file.

From the [PolicySpi API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/PolicySpi.html), you can see that a PolicySpi object features 4 methods:

1. [engineGetPermissions(CodeSource codesource)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/PolicySpi.html#engineGetPermissions-java.security.CodeSource-)
2. [engineGetPermissions(ProtectionDomain domain)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/PolicySpi.html#engineGetPermissions-java.security.ProtectionDomain-)
3. [engineImplies(ProtectionDomain domain, Permission permission)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/PolicySpi.html#engineImplies-java.security.ProtectionDomain-java.security.Permission-)
4. [engineRefresh()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/PolicySpi.html#engineRefresh--)

However, you might not need **PolicySpi** as there are easier solutions to check permissions.

See:

- [Security Manager vs Access Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555026/security-manager-vs-access-controller)
- [AccessController usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703234/accesscontroller-usage)

Since you haven't specified what kind of permission you will grant, I will assume it is a permission concerning a [java.security.CodeSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/CodeSource.html) object.

To check *all* current permissions for a file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CodeSource source;

    try {
      source = new CodeSource(new URL("file:/c:/*"), (java.security.cert.Certificate[]) null);

      Policy policy = Policy.getPolicy();
      System.out.println(policy.getPermissions(source));

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

A nice example for the `SecurityManager checkPermission()` is [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/securitymanager_checkpermission_object.htm).

For checking specific [FilePermission](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilePermission.html)s, you can use:

```
FilePermission perm = new FilePermission("path/file", "read");
AccessController.checkPermission(perm);
```

### Granting permissions

Granting permissions at runtime can be done with [java.lang.RuntimePermission](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimePermission.html).

For other examples of how to grant permissions to a file, I suggest you read the following:

- [Access Control Mechanisms and Algorithms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/spec/security-spec.doc4.html)
- [Configuring spi.policy files](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdoc400/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.iseries.doc/info/ae/ae/tsec_spipolicy.html)
- [Security Managers and Permissions](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1187967&seqNum=3)

---

That should bring you a long way! Good luck!

Comment: The idea is to create a runtime checking of a custom Permission (MyPermission). Since the checking may vary during runtime, I need a implementation without policy file. I already used AccessController.checkPermission(). The only thing is I need this method to go to a interface which provides runtime information

Comment: According to [THIS](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~paul8/jdk1.2beta3/docs/api/java.security.AccessController.html), `There is only one instance of AccessController in each Java runtime.`. This means that the default context is already the context of the current `runtime`.

Comment: Thats true, I'am using AccessController.checkPermission which uses the Policy in its turn. The Policy should do specific checking, for instance if the time is between 8:00 and 10:00 the permission is allowed otherwise it is not allowed. 

But that is possible especially with the 'configuring spi.policy files' I now know how to start using it. Thx.

Comment: @OblongZebra: Too bad of your reputation bounty :( You didn't use it!

Comment: Sorry I reacted to late. I requested stackoverflow to allow you the bounty anyway, hope they grant it.

Answer (score 0):

The [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22618462/3986374) answer lists alternatives to using `PolicySpi` (and more generally custom `Policy` implementations ). This answer will instead give a simplistic example on how a `PolicySpi` implementation can actually be used as a replacement of the system-default `Policy`.

1. Author a JCA [`Provider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Provider.html).

   ```
   package com.example;

   import java.security.AccessController;
   import java.security.PrivilegedAction;
   import java.security.Provider;

   public final class TestProvider extends Provider {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 5544432861418770903L;

       public TestProvider() {
           super("TestProvider", 1, "TestProvider 1.0");
           AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction<Void>) () -> {
               putService(new TestPolicySpiService(this));
               return null;
           });
       }

   }
   ```
2. Author the sole [`Service`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Provider.Service.html) descriptor encapsulated by the provider.

   ```
   package com.example;

   import java.security.Policy.Parameters;
   import java.security.PolicySpi;
   import java.security.Provider;
   import java.security.Provider.Service;
   import java.util.Collections;

   final class TestPolicySpiService extends Service {

       TestPolicySpiService(Provider p) {
           super(p, "Policy", "TestPolicy", PolicySpi.class.getName(), Collections.emptyList(), Collections.emptyMap());
       }

       @Override
       public PolicySpi newInstance(Object constructorParameter) {
           Parameters policyParams = null;
           if (constructorParameter instanceof Parameters) {
               policyParams = (Parameters) constructorParameter;
           }
           return new TestPolicySpi(policyParams);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean supportsParameter(Object parameter) {
           return parameter instanceof Parameters;
       }

   }
   ```
3. Author the actual service (the `PolicySpi` implementation in this case) that the service descriptor produces.

   ```
   package com.example;

   import java.security.Permission;
   import java.security.Policy.Parameters;
   import java.security.PolicySpi;
   import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

   final class TestPolicySpi extends PolicySpi {

       TestPolicySpi(Parameters policyParams) {}

       @Override
       protected boolean engineImplies(ProtectionDomain domain, Permission permission) {
           // deny unconditionally
           return false;
       }

   }
   ```
4. Register the provider either statically, by modifying the `security.provider.n` properties in `JAVA_HOME/lib/security/java.security`, or programmatically, via `java.security.Security.addProvider(Provider)` / `java.security.Security.insertProviderAt(Provider, int)`.
5. Replace the default `Policy`.

   ```
   package com.example;

   import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
   import java.security.Policy;

   public class Main {

       public static void main(String... args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
           // the following assumes that the provider has been statically registered
           Policy.setPolicy(Policy.getInstance("TestPolicy", null));
           System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());

           // test
           System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home")); // should raise AccessControlException
       }

   }
   ```

***Is there a better way to do this?***

There certainly is a *less involved* way, as long as the consequent tight coupling between application and policy does not irk you too badly: Just subclass `Policy` directly and pass an instance of your implementation to `Policy.setPolicy(Policy)`.

---

Further reading:

- [Java Cryptography Architecture (JCA) Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html)
- [How to Implement a Provider in the Java Cryptography Architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html)
- [Standard Algorithm Name Documentation for JDK 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html)
- [Troubleshooting Security](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/troubleshooting-security.html)

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 6, the default implementation for `PolicySpi` is `sun.security.provider.PolicySpiFile`. You can get inspired from the [source code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/478a4add975b/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/PolicySpiFile.java) of `PolicySpiFile`:

```
package sun.security.provider;

import java.security.CodeSource;
import java.security.Permission;
import java.security.PermissionCollection;
import java.security.Policy;
import java.security.PolicySpi;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;
import java.security.URIParameter;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

/**
 * This class wraps the PolicyFile subclass implementation of Policy
 * inside a PolicySpi implementation that is available from the SUN provider
 * via the Policy.getInstance calls.
 *
 */
public final class PolicySpiFile extends PolicySpi {

    private PolicyFile pf;

    public PolicySpiFile(Policy.Parameters params) {

        if (params == null) {
            pf = new PolicyFile();
        } else {
            if (!(params instanceof URIParameter)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException
                        ("Unrecognized policy parameter: " + params);
            }
            URIParameter uriParam = (URIParameter)params;
            try {
                pf = new PolicyFile(uriParam.getURI().toURL());
            } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid URIParameter", mue);
            }
        }
    }

    protected PermissionCollection engineGetPermissions(CodeSource codesource) {
        return pf.getPermissions(codesource);
    }

    protected PermissionCollection engineGetPermissions(ProtectionDomain d) {
        return pf.getPermissions(d);
    }

    protected boolean engineImplies(ProtectionDomain d, Permission p) {
        return pf.implies(d, p);
    }

    protected void engineRefresh() {
        pf.refresh();
    }
}
```